# Resources to help a recent statistics graduate deal with real world statistical problems

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, inference, references

I recently got my master's in biostatistics, so I know the basics. However in my work there are many situations where people ask me "would it be statistically valid to do xyz" and I really don't know what to say because it's such a specific situation that I've never dealt with before. For example, I recently had a client who was trying to compare two groups with vastly different sample size and demographics.

I realize this is a shot in the dark but is anybody aware of a book or something where the authors go through a variety of real world statistical problems - in areas such as basic hypothesis testing, regression, clustering? Or just any advice in general for me.

Comment: The Biostatistics book by Pagano and Gauvreau is mostly based on actual, usually substantial, medical and biostat studies. It may not be an ideal textbook for a first introduction because of its lack of summaries of key equations and principles (e.g., for exam study), but it may be better than most for your purposes. // All such recommendations, including this one, are biased personal opinions, so use your own judgment. // Also when you understand resources and goals for a particular project clearly enough to ask a good question, ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Cross Validated!

I wouldn’t have been able to benefit from Cross Validated without going to graduate school, but I feel like I’ve learned more by reading and posting here. That sounds like your situation, where you know the basics but want to go to that next level.